# Why am I able to duplicate entries in a mongodb using mongol by msavin even though I don't have a method allowing for that?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've been using a pretty cool [package](https://github.com/msavin/Mongol) by Max Savin to monitor what is going on in the database and I noticed it has a "duplicate" function. This allows me to enter things into the database even though I haven't defined a method to allow for this. Ie I've removed the `insecure` package and have methods to allow entering info into the database.

Is this expected behaviour?

From the FAQ on the github page it seems yes? But I'm not sure.

> Does Mongol require insecure to work? No, Mongol has special set of
>   method's that allow it to interact with the database without
>   disrupting your application permissions.
>
> Is there a security risk to using Mongol? Since Mongol is a debugOnly
>   package, Meteor's build process will not compile it into production
>   code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior, this package has its own server-side methods, and it even bypasses common validation libraries: https://github.com/msavin/Mongol/blob/94ede16c02c3764448918c94b4d443528d227e9f/server/methods.js#L59